# QPixmap load many images in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to load images from a folder and view the previous and next images by clicking a button on the `GUI` (similar to Windows Image Viewer). The names of the images in this folder are `xxxx_00.jpg` to `xxxx_99.jpg`, so I use `index++` and `index--` to change the filename when clicking the buttons.

My codes work well for displaying the first image, but when I click a button to view the previous or the next images, it always shows

> QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap

and returns an empty image (the first image disappeared but new image didn't display).

Here's my code:

In mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()   //previous image
{
    if (index < 1)
    {
        index = 99;
        QLabel label;
        label.setText("Go back");
        label.show();
    }
    else
    {
        index--;
    }
    RefreshFilename();
    loadimage();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()   //next image
{
    if (index > 98)
    {
        index = 0;
        QLabel label;
        label.setText("ALL SET");
        label.show();
    }
    else
    {
        index = index + 1;
    }
    RefreshFilename();
    loadimage();
}


void MainWindow::loadimage()
{
   // image.load(filename);
   // im = image.scaled(500,500,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    imageObject = new QImage();
    imageObject->load(filename);
    image = QPixmap::fromImage(*imageObject);
    im = image.scaled(400,400,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->addPixmap(image);
    scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
    ui->mainimage->setScene(scene);
}
```

I have spent 2 whole days on debugging this, but still have no idea. I am looking forward to any advice and support!

BTW The `Refreshfilename` Function works fine, so I did not paste it here.

Comment: you have QLabel * label member of the class and then in the constructor you initialize it: label = new QLabel; and then reuse the label: label-> setPixmap (); label-> show () ;. Remember that local variables are deleted when the function is finished. Do not you think that the QLabels you declare are local?

Comment: Yeah but I didn't use Qlabel to show the images. I only used QLabel to print some notes when click the button. I use imageObject, image, scene etc. to display the images and these variables are all public member in class Mainwindow.

Comment: the same thing can be done just change label->setPixmap(...) to label->setText(...)

Comment: Yeah but the reason I use *scene to display the image is I want the image shows on the mainwindow, if I use label it displays in a new window. Is it because the scene cannot be reloaded in the mainwindow?

Comment: you talk about the scene but I do not see any of it, if you want help you should provide a [mcve], can you do it?

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

Since I do not know what `RefreshFilename();` does, I cannot tell exactly what the cause is.

However, I see a major flaw in your code, i.e. you create a new scene each time `MainWindow::loadimage` is called and this causes a memory leak.

When you provide more details I will be more specific here.

## Solution

- Set the scene once and add a *QGraphicsPixmapItem* to it, then in the `loadImage` update the pixmap of the item.
- Keep the current number in a class attribute.

Again, I will be more specific once details are added.

## Example

In any case (waiting for you to provide a MVCE), I have prepared a working example according to your task description:

```
#define IMAGE_COUNT 99

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_imgNum(0),
    m_item(new QGraphicsPixmapItem())
{
    auto *widget = new QWidget(this);
    auto *layoutMain = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    auto *layoutButtons = new QHBoxLayout();
    auto *btnPrev = new QPushButton(tr("Previous"), this);
    auto *btnNext = new QPushButton(tr("Next"), this);
    auto *view = new QGraphicsView(this);

    view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
    view->scene()->addItem(m_item);

    layoutButtons->addStretch();
    layoutButtons->addWidget(btnPrev);
    layoutButtons->addWidget(btnNext);
    layoutButtons->addStretch();

    layoutMain->addWidget(view);
    layoutMain->addLayout(layoutButtons);

    setCentralWidget(widget);
    resize(640, 480);
    loadImage();

    connect(btnPrev, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){
        if (m_imgNum > 0)
            m_imgNum--;
        else
            m_imgNum = IMAGE_COUNT;

        loadImage();
    });

    connect(btnNext, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){
        if (m_imgNum < IMAGE_COUNT)
            m_imgNum++;
        else
            m_imgNum = 0;

        loadImage();
    });
}

void MainWindow::loadImage()
{
    m_item->setPixmap(QString("images/image_%1.jpg").arg(m_imgNum, 2, 10, QChar('0')));
}
```

where `m_imgNum`, `m_item` and `loadImage` are declared in the header as:

```
private:
    inline void loadImage();

    int m_imgNum;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *m_item;
```